# Theano installation in Windows 32bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano

I am trying to install Theano library on a windows 32-bit machine. I've already installed python 2.7, numpy, scipy, mingw.  The next dependency is blas.  How can I install it on Windows? I've also installed canopy in order to install pip. The next steps are to install Theano with:

```
pip install Theano 
sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps theano
git clone git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
cd Theano
python setup.py develop
```

Am I missing any step except in blas installation?  When I try to use the canopy platform to perform the installation, I've noticed that I couldn't install from the package manager the needed dependencies  “mingw 4.5.2” and “libpython 1.2”.

I also tried to follow AnacondaCE instructions. I've downloaded it and configured it using Windows installer for Theano on AnacondaCE for Windows configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install numpy/scipy/mingw? I think they are installed by default with canopy. As you tried many things, I would suggest that you remove all other python installation and only keep canopy. Canopy provide blas, so you don't need to install one. It is better to install the academic/full version of canopy as it provide a faster BLAS. Their should be newer version of mingw and libpython in canopy since the instruction was done. Install them.

Then this is done, you only need to install theano with this command:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps Theano
```

All the command you provides are different way to install Theano. You only need one! If you want the development version, you can use this instead:

```
git clone git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
cd Theano
python setup.py develop
```